# Realtek audio drivers broken (no audio configuration possible) after updating

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I updated my Realtek audio drivers to version 2.73, hoping that it would fix the audio stuttering that starts to appear after ~16 hours runtime. That plan backfired and now I'm stuck with no audio devices working or having any output channels at all. I tried reverting to pre-uninstalling the driver, but that didn't change the result, at all.

What can i do to regain audio and control of said audio? I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (Build 7601) and my mainboard is an AsRock 970 Extreme 3.

---

What apparently many don't see, is that the problem is not the driver but whatever is interacting with it. The driver works fine (or I'll have no devices listed), the problem is that i can't change the audio device settings, at all. All sliders and buttons are gone for those devices.

Anyway, after the fifth uninstall and reinstall of the drivers, i decided to just reinstall Windows. And look at that, everything is working again.

Comment: Did you tried Roll Back in Device Manager.?

Comment: Yeah, i did. All it does is roll back to the microsoft drivers, which have the same problem (configure button not working, volume sliders missing). By now, i think this problem is related to some registry error caused by windows's multimedia service.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage device drivers in Device Manager. To access this, you can right-click Computer in the Start Menu, click Manage and in the dropdown tree on the left, go to device manager. In the window on the right, you can find your device and roll-back drivers, or disable, enable etc...

Or, if documents are not a problem, try a System Restore to an even earlier point. You can access System Restore by going to Control Panel > System > View system properties > System Restore.

If I have helped, please award me some rep points!

Thanks

Comment: Remove the drivers completely -- remove the associated devices from the device manager (NOT DISABLE).  Restart.  Windows 7 should now re-install the original drivers.  If it doesn't, and shows the devices with the yellow !, then re-add them from the original source (mfr's disk or download older version.)

Comment: @Debra I did remove the drivers completely (as well as "uninstall" the hardware from windows), the next boot up it will just have the default microsoft drivers there, and the problem is still not solved. I'm going for the reinstall now, that will definitely solve it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install Windows again. Did you ever used Driver Booster or DriverMax ? Try any of these softwares. Download any of these, install and check for driver updates. If you found an update for Audio Driver, download it and install. This will fix your problem surely.

Comment: I don't think any of those can help an issue with the driver. After all, 2.73 is the newest official version for that chipset, as you can see by visiting www.realtek.com.tw.

Comment: @Xaymar Just roll back and try what I said. It will work.

Comment: Neither of those programs helped my problem. Both tried to install 2.71, a version that causes bluescreens on my system. I'll just reinstall now.

Comment: @Xaymar The blue screen appears when the Realtek starts to install.

Comment: No, the bluescreen appears after a while, not when it starts to install. Doesn't matter now though, reinstall is done and everything works again.